# Pod update/install is missing 1 framework Target Support Files

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I had 6 pods in the target. After doing pod install, 5 pods are being added in Target Support Files but 1 pod is being missed.

Comment: Check on git either its pod is available or not

Comment: All 6 pods are in local.

Comment: Please tell me the name of the pod that is not installing

Comment: Also, what does your pod file look like?