# Pods are missing in Targets Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, mapbox-ios

I'm working with MapBox Search API. To avail MapBox libraries -

1. Create a new Project in Xcode
2. Close that project and open that project folder in terminal
3. Run `pod init`
4. Add these to my Podfile -

   target 'MapBox' do 
    use_frameworks! 
   pod 'MapboxSearchUI', ">= 1.0.0-beta.3", "< 2.0" 
   end
5. Run `pod Install` and got this -

   Analyzing dependencies 
   Downloading dependencies 
   Using MapboxCommon (9.0.2) 
   Using MapboxMobileEvents (0.10.8) 
   Using MapboxSearch (1.0.0-beta.4) 
   Using MapboxSearchUI (1.0.0-beta.4) 
   Generating Pods project 
   Integrating client project 
   Sending stats 
   Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.
6. [But I'm getting error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67043506/framework-not-found-mapboxcommon-xcframework-ios-xcode)
7. I checked in pods targets and found out that only one pod listed in targets and rests are not -

Targets list in Xcode -

[image: Targets]

And installed pod list in projects pod directory -

[image: installed pods]

So How can I add the other pods in Xcode Targets?

**N.B:** I've found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776270/pod-update-install-is-missing-1-framework-target-support-files) but there are no answares in that and that question is not that elaborative.